# Remove item from cart during CartChangedEvent in Shopware (PHP)

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I am trying to remove a LineItem from the cart during the CartChangedEvent  but it does not work. I tried

```
public function cartChangedEvent(CartChangedEvent $pEvent)
{
    $lineItems = $pEvent->getCart()->getLineItems();
    $x = $lineItems->count();
    $lineItems->removeElement($pEvent->getCart()->getLineItems()->first());
    $lineItems->count(); // The size is $x - 1 now
    $pEvent->getCart()->setLineItems($lineItems);
}
```

But that does not work. The line items list gets changed, but the cart does not change even though I am using setLineItems

Comment: I'm not quite sure, so I'm leaving this as a comment:
Maybe you need to persist the cart using the CartPersister, see for example here: www/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Cart/CartRuleLoader.php:168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cart needs to be persisted to be saved. To do that you have to add:

```
<argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\CartPersister"/>
```

To your service in the service.xml to receive a CartPersister. After you changed the line items you have to call save(Cart $cart, SalesChannelContext $context) on the CartPersister.